# Move external libraries to wwwroot folder with gulp

Tags: javascript, build, npm, gulp, asp.net-core

I am using VS 2015 + ASP.net vnext + Angular 2 + Typescript + gulp.js. I have automated my `scripts/**/*.ts` files moving to the `wwwroot/app` folder. Now I want to do the same for my libraries like Angular 2. I want that a gulp process injects

- `angular.js` inside `index.html` inside the `<environment names="Development">` node;
- `angular.min.js` inside `index.html` inside the `<environment names="Production">` node.

Of course I want that this to happen for all my libs automatically,  without having knowledge about a library:

- `<any>.min.js` (production)
- `<any>.js` (development)

The minification of `any.js` can be done by me.

Actually I would just have to regard all `dependencies` in `package.json`... but then I am lost.

Can my idea be done or does there maybe already exist a tool? Or should the workflow broken into more manual steps like I have to copy/paste a certain library?

Or is it possible to take the `dependencies` name and concat it with `.js` then search this file under the `node_modules` folder... (kind of hacky and not safe...)

**UPDATE**

Rephrase/Refine my question:

How can I automatically add my npm `dependencies` (not `devDependencies`) to the environment `"Development"` node when triggering a certain event like build/clear/etc...

Answer (score 3):

There is a little tag helper for this, called `asp-src-include`.

Imagine the case where you have a handful of *.js files you want to include:

```
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app/controller/controllerA.js"></script>
<script src="/app/controller/controllerB.js"></script>
<script src="/app/service/userservice.js"></script>
```

etc. You can include all of these with a single `´ tag.

```
<script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.js"></script>
```

So for Production/Development deployment your Razor markup may look  like

```
<environment names="Development">            
    <script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script asp-src-include="~/app/**/*.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

For this you need the `@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"` (starting with RC1 or RC2 it's ' @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers' - without the double-quotes ) declaration in your `*.cshtml` files or inside your `_Layout.cshtml`.

**edit**

There is an module called `gulp-npm-files` that does something similar, it copies all *.js files into the target folders. You can see it's source on [GitHub](https://github.com/goodseller/gulp-npm-files/blob/master/index.js) in case you want write your own module to extend the functionality.

But that may not be exactly what you want, as the folders often contain multiple files, for example `angular2` (AngularJS 2.0) contains dozen of files (*.js and *.ts), but you're mostly only interested in the compiled/minified ones, found in `angular2/bundles/*` like `angular2.js`, `angular2.min.js` or `angular.dev.js`.

The `package.json` of the particular dependency provides no information on where to find this compiled files. So I guess, there's no way to automate this unless you want to copy all of the files to `wwwroot` which makes no sense in my eyes, especially if you want to use `asp-src-include`, as it makes no difference on what it includes, so you want to minimize the number of *.js files in your `wwwroot` folder.

I guess the best you can do is to manually copy the dependencies via gulp task and then use `asp-src-include` to automatically include them into your razor generated html files.

Comment: yes I totally forgot I cant use a static html file when I want to use razor... I just deleted my razor yesterday haha, now I gotta revert. asp-src-include also accepts a comma seperated array of strings/path thats cool so you can include app .js and lib .js files. Your answer is not yet a solution because my question was about the handling of the libs files despite I am grateful for the asp-src-include hint!

Comment: To rephrase my problem in short words:"How can I automatically add my npm dependencies (not devDependencies) to the environment "Development" node when triggering a certain event like build/clear/etc...

Comment: @Pascal: Updated the post with `gulp-npm-files` npm package, but I don't think there is an reliable way to automate it w/o copying all of the files inside the package (which conflicts the `asp-src-include` method above)

Comment: Funny we both are from Germany and 5 and a half year on SO ;-) Yes you exactly hit my problem. Reliability of recognizing... bower has the main property telling what is the main file, npm has package.json with 'depencies' like 'angular2'. The folder name is 'angular2' too. That could be an accident but I do not think. From that point we can search the angular2.js. That worked too, but maybe only in the angular2 case.

Comment: Yes for now I will gulp copy my libraries from node_modules folder to the wwwroot/lib/here and use the asp-src-include using development. When I build for production I gulp bundle and then copy the bundle to wwwroot/lib/all.min.js. Maybe later I will try to make a wiredep task that works for .cshtml files...but I guess herein wait some obstackles ;-)

Comment: @Pascal: There is a `main` in package.json, but it has a different meaning. It just declares the file that contains the module export. On very simple modules, its the only file. On complex ones it just defines the requires and gives an entry point to the module. in bower example its 1 file per type (js, scss) and suggested to use source files with exports rather than minified or distribution files https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md  https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: On other side it makes perfect sense, that there is no automatic mechanism. Most of the npm/power packages are complex and offer multiple bundles with all features or some with basic bundles. Some offer extensions/plugins, whereas other offer language files and you may only need 2 or 3 out of the 30+ available language files. Only the developer knows which files he exactly needs for his project

Comment: You are right but wiredep goes that one step further. It allows to override default patterns by defining a custom path to a file.js. But well in the end my project has a handful libs why not copy them via gulp ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you want to inject the scripts automatically into your HTML, right? You can use the [Wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep) module for that.

And for copying the assets to an other folder, there are many modules to copy or link files from one folder to another. [Gulp-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy) is the first one i could find.

Comment: Your solution answer is a tiny partial ;-) I do not want to use stuff like:   <!-- bower:js -->
Its not needed. I have that already in my asp.net project html file with the <environtment name="development" >scripts go here </...> Please answer in context of asp.net.

Comment: @Pascal: You sure you can use <environment> tag in plain simple html files, that even may be in the `wwwroot` folder? As far as i know it's part of Razor and will just work there and even then only if the `@addTagHelper` in your `.cshtml` or `_Layout.cshtml`. I don't have the suitable environment to try it out here though..